# Unable to send message using smslib

Tags: java, smslib

I am using a Simado GDT11 modem and Prolific USB to Serial port driver. The new connection appears in my Device Manager > Ports list. However, I am unable to send messages using smslib.

I am using the basic class as specified in the smslib examples, but there is always some error which states that there is no response from the device. I have added the polling parameters because of the use of USB port but to no avail. Commtest Utility is able to connect to the same port, so I don't think the port number is an issue.

Stacktrace:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (smslib).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.smslib.TimeoutException: No response from device.
  at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver$CharQueue.get(AModemDriver.java:535)
  at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:338)
  at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.getResponse(AModemDriver.java:313)
  at org.smslib.modem.athandler.ATHandler.getSimStatus(ATHandler.java:145)
  at org.smslib.modem.AModemDriver.connect(AModemDriver.java:132)
  at org.smslib.modem.ModemGateway.startGateway(ModemGateway.java:189)
  at org.smslib.Service$1Starter.run(Service.java:277)
```

Code:

```
public class SendMessage {

public void doIt() throws Exception
{
    SerialModemGateway gateway = new SerialModemGateway("modem.com4", "COM4", 115200, "Simado", "GDT11");
    try {
        OutboundNotification outboundNotification = new OutboundNotification();
        System.out.println("Example: Send message from a serial gsm modem.");
        System.out.println(Library.getLibraryDescription());
        System.out.println("Version: " + Library.getLibraryVersion());
        gateway.setInbound(false);
        gateway.setOutbound(true);
        gateway.setSimPin("0000");
        // Explicit SMSC address set is required for some modems.
        // Below is for VODAFONE GREECE - be sure to set your own!
        gateway.setSmscNumber("+919560734413");
        Service.getInstance().setOutboundMessageNotification(outboundNotification);
        Service.getInstance().addGateway(gateway);
        Service.getInstance().S.SERIAL_NOFLUSH = true;
        Service.getInstance().S.SERIAL_POLLING = true;
        Service.getInstance().S.SERIAL_POLLING_INTERVAL = 200;
        Service.getInstance().startService();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Modem Information:");
        System.out.println("  Manufacturer: " + gateway.getManufacturer());
        System.out.println("  Model: " + gateway.getModel());
        System.out.println("  Serial No: " + gateway.getSerialNo());
        System.out.println("  SIM IMSI: " + gateway.getImsi());
        System.out.println("  Signal Level: " + gateway.getSignalLevel() + " dBm");
        System.out.println("  Battery Level: " + gateway.getBatteryLevel() + "%");
        System.out.println();
        // Send a message synchronously.
        OutboundMessage msg = new OutboundMessage("+918095065000", "Hello from SMSLib!");
        Service.getInstance().sendMessage(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
    } finally {
        gateway.stopGateway();
        Service.getInstance().stopService();
    }

}

public class OutboundNotification implements IOutboundMessageNotification
{
    public void process(AGateway gateway, OutboundMessage msg)
    {
        System.out.println("Outbound handler called from Gateway: " + gateway.getGatewayId());
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    SendMessage app = new SendMessage();
    try
    {
        app.doIt();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. The code is correct. Apparently, using a SIM card which is on roaming isn't the best idea. I shifted to a local SIM card, and the message was sent.

Furthermore, I was using a USB to COM port emulator ([Prolific USB-Serial](http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=225&pcid=41)) due to which the modem was not initializing while running the code.

To solve this, I ran the initialization command(`AT + CMGF = 1`) on server start up.